# Discord.js if user has role?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need help with my bot.
My bot should only respond if a user has a specific role. It should be definable by name and not by ID.
I user Discord.js 12.0.2

my code

```
//DBD embed
client.on("message", async message => {
  let cmd = message
    if (message.content === '/code-embed') {
      message.channel.send("Der angefragte Bot code", { files: [ "./dbd/embed.txt" ] })
}})
```

Comment: can you show what you tried? It's not clear how you want this implemented.

Comment: I updated it...

Comment: So, just checking. You want to check if the bot has a role or if the user has a role?

Comment: I want to check whether the user has a role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `some()` on the `roles` collection of the `GuildMember` to check if they have a specific role.

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === 'RoleName')) return
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to SO, if an answer solves your question then accept it using the tick mark next to it to let others know what worked as well as that the question was answered.